# Kernel Panic, Can I get specific info from this screenshot I have?

Tags: boot, kernel

here are the specs for my desktop:

- Linux Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS & Windows 7
- HP pavilion p6000, AMD64

Here´s the problem details:

- Kernel panic error (Ubuntu) and Blue Screen of Death (Windows)
- Computer doesn't start up at all sometimes (it powers on but does not boot)
- Standby sometimes doesn't awake
- Keyboard and mouse freeze
- [Screenshot of latest bug. Sorry for potato quality. [1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sYvQ.jpg)

Comment: Screenshot indicates `BUG: Bad rss-counter state` but I agree: If both, Windows and Linux have issues, it's probably hardware-related.

Comment: Is there way for me to find out exactly which device is faulty? I did the memtets and harddisk test already and things seemed to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens on both Linux and Windows, it's almost certainly faulty hardware. Have you done a memtest, for starters? (Boot Ubuntu desktop CD, choose "test memory".)

Comment: Yes I did. I did the memtest which passed twice with no issues and that was fine. Then I did another test with the Disk Utility which showed my harddisks were fine... I'm a little confused on what to do next really.

Comment: What's the Windows BSOD message?